# Symfony form mime-types should only accept PDF-files

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I am trying to make my Symfony2 program only accept PDF-files. 
In the entity class I have:

```
/**
 * File
 *
 * @var File
 *
 * @Assert\File(
 *      maxSize = "5M",
 *      mimeTypes = {"application/pdf", "application/x-pdf"},
 *      maxSizeMessage = "The maxmimum allowed file size is 5M.",
 *      mimeTypesMessage = "Please upload a valid PDF"
 * )
 */
protected $file;
```

The question is why I still can upload other files. I am currently uploading through REST API.

The code:

```
    public function postFileAction(Request $request){

    $name = $request->get('name');
    $path = $request->get('path');
    $file = $request->files->get('file');

    $filesTest = new FilesTest();
    $filesTest->setName($name);
    $filesTest->setFile($file);;

    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $manager->persist($filesTest);
    $manager->flush();
    }
```

I am new at symfony2 so I might have misunderstood how to handle this. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Because validation is only triggered when using `$form->isValid()` or using validator service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually validating those validation rules.

Try this:

```
public function postFileAction(Request $request)
{
    $name = $request->get('name');
    $path = $request->get('path');
    $file = $request->files->get('file');

    $filesTest = new FilesTest();
    $filesTest->setName($name);
    $filesTest->setFile($file);

    $validator = $this->get('validator'); // Assuming ContainerAware
    $errors    = $validator->validate($filesTest);

    if (count($errors) > 0) {
        // Handle your errors here
    } else {
        $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $manager->persist($filesTest);
        $manager->flush();
    }

    // Return your response etc...
}
```

If you want more information about validating this way, take a look here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html

While working with REST you can also spoof form submissions, so, don't rule out using forms too.

Answer (score 1):

Since Symfony 3.4, if you want to validate only one field, you can use:

```
public function validateField(ValidatorInterface $validator){

    $violations = $validator->validatePropertyValue(
        $entity, 
        'propertyName',
        $propertyValue
    );

    foreach ($violations as $violation) {
        // $violation->getMessage();
    }
}
```